# Flash Actionscript 3 error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs

Tags: php, mysql, database, actionscript-3

Here is the full error:

```
Error: 
Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.
    at Error$/throwError()
    at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
    at flash.net::URLVariables()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

I cant get this to work for the life of me. I have tried everything I can find online. Im beginning to think it may be an error in my PHP. In debug mode it states that I have sandbox security error. To my knowledge the should be exempt in testing mode.
AS3 Code:

```
function NewEntry(ev:Event):void{
var Data:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var SystemLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var DatabaseRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("myphpscript.php");
DatabaseRequest.data = Data;
SystemLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
DatabaseRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
    Data.First_Name = FirstName.text
    Data.Last_Name = LastName.text
    Data.UserBirthday = DOB_year.text
    Data.PhoneNo = PhoneNum.text
    Data.Email = UserEmail.text
    Data.requester = "NewSale";
    SystemLoader.load(DatabaseRequest);
    SystemLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, receiveLoad);
}
function receiveLoad(ev:Event):void{
    trace("DONE");
}
```

Here is my fixed php code:

```
<?php

// Establish secure connection
$link = mysql_connect('spvfcorg.ipagemysql.com', 'events_admin', 'SPVFC6events'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully'; 
mysql_select_db(events_60); 


if ($_POST['requester'] == "NewSale") {

     $FirstName = $_POST['First_Name'];
     $LastName = $_POST['Last_Name'];
     $Birthday = $_POST['UserBirthday'];
     $PhoneNumber = $_POST['PhoneNo'];
     $Email = $_POST['UserEmail'];

$mysqli_query = mysql_query($link, "INSERT INTO events_60 (LastName, FirstName, Birthday,           Phone, email) 
        VALUES('LastName','$FirstName','$Birthday', '$PhoneNumber', 'Email')");

echo ("System_Updated");
} // close first if for post

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// close mysql connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505720/error-2101-the-string-passed-to-urlvariables-decode-must-be-a-url-encoded) and [#2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500974/2101-the-string-passed-to-urlvariables-decode-must-be-a-url-encoded-query-st)

Comment: Your code makes absolutely no sense. You do an INSERT query, then try to `fetch()` from the handle? An insert query does NOT return any result rows. There's also syntax errors in the query

Comment: Marc B, I apologize about my poor php syntax. I am new to the language and think I have fixed it.